# What does jg do after cmpl $0x4, (%rsp)?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, att

I'm specifically dealing with:

```
   0x0000000000401141 <+165>:   cmpl   $0x4,(%rsp)
   0x0000000000401145 <+169>:   jg     0x401156 <phase_3+186>
```

And I know 5 is in (%rsp) by:

```
(gdb) x/d $rsp
0x7fffffffe320: 5
```

Shouldn't the program *not* jump, since 4 is not greater than 5? But it does, and I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't it not make a difference that it's a signed jump, because neither are negative?

Comment: at&t has operands reversed. If you are confused you can switch gdb to intel syntax by `set disassembly-flavor intel`

Comment: @Jester Oh, thanks a lot.